# Recursive function and React in Crome debug VM - a mess

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

First, let me explain what I want to do.
I have tree-like data structure, with arbitrary depth from which i want to make a list of all non-leaf branches which I pass as props to Child component.
Data set and recursive function are bellow.

Problem:
I get double data in array! I noticed that function `getBranches()` is called also in chrome VM and it just appends same data again to already existing array. See pic bellow.
Is my approach fundamentally wrong? What to do?

```
const treeData = {
'first-level-node-1': {               // key
  label: 'Regija',
  type: TYPES[1],
  index: 0, // rendering order
  url: 'http://opa.com',     
  nodes: {
    'second-level-node-1': {
      label: 'Bolnica BN',
      index: 0,
      type: 1,
      nodes: {
        'third-level-node-1': {
          label: 'Konektor Sysmex',
          index: 0,
          nodes: {}, 
          type: TYPES[0]
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
'first-level-node-2': {
  label: 'Regija 2',
  index: 1,
  type: TYPES[1],
  nodes: {
    '2-1': {
      label: 'Dz Trebinje',
      index: 0,
      type: 1,
      nodes: {
        '3-1': {
          label: 'Konektor Biomerux',
          index: 0,
          hasNodes: false,
          type: TYPES[0],
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

};

My  `getBranches()`  function:

```
const getBranches = (treeData) => {
console.log('i= ',i++)
Object.keys(treeData).forEach((key) => {
    if (treeData[key].type!==TYPES[0]) {
        branches.push({key: key, label: treeData[key].label});
        console.log({key: key, label: treeData[key].label})
        treeData[key].nodes && getBranches(treeData[key].nodes)
    };
});
return [...branches];
```

};

My Component:

```
const Sites = () => {

const branches = getBranches(treeData);

console.log(branches);
//const [data, setData] = useState(treeData);

return (
    <Container fluid="md">
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <MyTreeView data={treeData}/>
            </Col>
            <Col>
                <BranchView
                    sites={treeData}
                    parentList={branches}
                />
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>
);
```

};

Some additional info:

branch vs leaf is distinguished by property  `type`

The Picture. Notice the  `i` s

[image: The picture. Notice the i's]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is simply that you don't declare `branches` inside your function, making it a global variable.  So the next time the function is run, you're appending to it.  Adding a `const` declaration should probably do.

That said, I think you can simplify `getBranches` in a clean manner:

```js
const getBranches = (o) => Object .entries (o) .flatMap (
  ([key, {label, type, nodes}]) => [
    ... (type == TYPES [0] ? [] : [{key, label}]), 
    ... (nodes ? getBranches (nodes) : [])
  ]
)

const TYPES = [0, 1]
const treeData = {"first-level-node-1": {label: "Regija", type: TYPES[1], index: 0, url: "http: //opa.com", nodes: {"second-level-node-1": {label: "Bolnica BN", index: 0, type: 1, nodes: {"third-level-node-1": {label: "Konektor Sysmex", index: 0, nodes: {}, type: TYPES[0]}}}}}, "first-level-node-2": {label: "Regija 2", index: 1, type: TYPES[1], nodes: {"2-1": {label: "Dz Trebinje", index: 0, type: 1, nodes: {"3-1": {label: "Konektor Biomerux", index: 0, hasNodes: false, type: TYPES[0]}}}}}}

console .log (getBranches (treeData))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Thank you very much!